# How do I continue once I beat level 7-7?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-returns

I am playing Donkey Kong Country Returns and I'm on level 7/7. When I beat that world it won't open a road to the new stage instead it opens a road that backtracks to level 7/5. Why? How do I continue?

Comment: If I had to take a guess, you may have found one of multiple exits to a stage, or a stage you previously beat might have multiple exits.  I suggest backtracking through previous stages and looking for things you might've missed.

Answer (score 4):

Levels 7-5, 7-6, and 7-7 have 3 secret switches that must be activated to continue to level 7-R.

[As per the level 7-5 description from IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/donkey-kong-country-returns/7-5_Cog_Jog):

> SECRET SWITCH
>    Ground pound where you see the downward pointing arrow made out of bananas. The wheel will turn and a hatch will open. Down the hatch with you and pound the big red button you find inside. What's it do? Well, when you hit the big red buttons in this and the two subsequent levels, level 7-R opens up. Needless to say, if you don't unlock this level, you're not going any further in this game than 7-7.

[For level 7-6](http://www.ign.com/wikis/donkey-kong-country-returns/7-6_Switcheroo):

> SECRET SWITCH
>    Hit the blue circle by the purple balls of electricity then run back to the left and ground pound the broken bit of flooring. The Blast Barrel underneath will lead you to this level's big red button.

[For level 7-7](http://www.ign.com/wikis/donkey-kong-country-returns/7-7_Music_Madness):

> SECRET SWITCH
>    Ground pound the metal slab between the two flame jets to reach this level's big red button.